# Which one is more efficient using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a collection with objects that contain a value field and I need reduce information objective which one is more efficent or better and why?.

```
 settings.filter {it.value != null }.forEach{
    doSomething ....
}

settings.forEach{
    if(it.value != null){
        doSomething ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` allocates a list, so the second one will be faster. But if your list isn’t many hundreds of items long, the difference is negligible and you should choose what you think is more readable code. In this case I think the second one is easier to read anyway.

Comment: So the first one create in memory a additional list, my app is going to handle hundreds parameter that could be a problem, so I'm going to choose the second one, thanks a lot

Comment: Hundreds of elements is very small for a List.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the internal implementation of filter function used in Kotlin Collection.

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return filterTo(ArrayList<T>(), predicate) // New Array List Object Creation
}

public inline fun <T, C : MutableCollection<in T>> Iterable<T>.filterTo(destination: C, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): C {
    for (element in this) if (predicate(element)) destination.add(element)
    return destination
}
```

Here you can see, it creates new list. It creates an empty arraylist and add filtered elements to new list.

Adding to Tenfour04's answer, for small list you can use filter as its more idiomatic. If you need to go with optimal way, you can use non null check.

Also you do this more idiomatically like this,

```
settings.filterNotNull().forEach {} //It also create extra memory.
```

Or you can use create your own idiomatic foreach extension function filtering null values, without creating extra space

```
fun <T> Iterable<T?>.forEachNonNull(a: (T) -> Unit) {
    for (i in this) {
        if (i != null){
            a.invoke(i)
        }
    }
}
```

You can use like this.

```
settings.forEachNonNull {
}
```

Comment: Too complete your answer, thank you a lot, in this scenario I can't use forEachNonNull because settings Object never is null, but this field value could be null, so you answer is useful to considerate in other cases, I appreciated.

Comment: Just because something is idiomatic doesn’t mean it’s recommended. An idiom is just a way of doing something that uses a pattern that is easily recognized. ‘If not null” is just as, if not more so, recognizable and readable.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think I have  mentioned that in other terms here.  "For small list you can use filter as its more idiomatic. If you need to go with optimal way, you can use non null check."

Comment: Oh okay . Got it.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, the first example will create a temporary list in memory. In practice, this isn't usually worth worrying about — but as you say, if the list could be very big (say, tens of thousands of items or more) then it could become significant.

However, there's a ‘best of both worlds’ option, which is to use a [sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html):

```
settings.asSequence()
        .filterNotNull()
        .forEach {
            // doSomething ....
        }
```

This *looks* like the first example (apart from the added `asSequence()` and line breaks), but performs about as well as the second. That's because sequences are evaluated lazily: in this case `filterNotNull()` doesn't create a new list, but adds an action that will be executed as part of the `forEach`. You can add futher processing steps in between, too, and nothing will actually get evaluated until it's needed.

There's a bit of overhead in setting it all up (which is why sequences aren't the default), but that overhead doesn't depend on the size of the list — so if you have big lists and/or lots of processing steps, it can save a lot of memory. (It can also save a lot of processing in cases where you're not using all the results, such as when the last operation is a `find()`.)

Comment: Its the same case if I configure like this ?

`settings.asSequence().filter{it.value != null}.forEach {
            // doSomething ....
        }`
and this doesn't affect the response time on backend?

Comment: Yeah; in a sequence, everything is lazy up until the last (‘terminal’) operation; it doesn't do any processing (except setting up the pipeline) until that terminal operation tries to get some data, and then it only does as much as it needs to, whether that's mapping or filtering or whatever else.

Comment: I knew the existence of sequences, but I'm going to more depth about this topic thanks